# According to what Dirac infer $\alpha$ and $\beta$ independent with momentum in dirac equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

[image: This is Dirac's article about dirac equation]

I have read something else that $\alpha$ is the velocity,why the velocity is independent with momentum?

Answer (score 0):

Components of velocity are derivatives of coordinates with respect to time. To calculate these derivatives, one can calculate the commutators of the coordinates with the Dirac Hamiltonian and obtain the relation between components of velocity and $\alpha_i$.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for inferring is that Dirac wanted to construct the equation linear in time derivatives, treating the relativistic equation as the equation on the one-particle wave-function. Expecting that this equation contains relativistic dispersion relation and taking into account that time derivative corresponds to energy operator and spatial derivative corresponds to momentum, we thus realize that the equation is expected to be also the first order in spatial derivatives, with no mixing terms involving different derivatives.

As for the statement that $\alpha$ is the velocity, it follows from the definition as the time derivative of the canonical coordinate.